# Checking for characters in an array element in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of type string that contains a bunch of lines of text that are broken up in the different elements of the array. I want to check which element contains the string Name: in it. The reason I need to do it like this is because Name can be in a different element when ran on different arrays. I cant use .contains on an array so I am not sure what to use.

Comment: think about what String.contains() does and how it relates to the structure of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String []array = new String[]{"foo","bar","the_string_you_are_looking_for"};

int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
   if (array[i].contains("the_string_you_are_looking_for"))
   {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Heisenbug `array.size()`: array has no method `size()`. Should be `array.length` :)

Comment: oh thanks, that's true. I'm switching between several languages these days..my fault

Comment: @Heisenbug It already is confusing enough with the different versions in Java to get the length of an container: array=length, String=length(), Collection=size()

Answer (score 2):

```
int getIndexOfElementContainingName(String[] myStringArray) {
    for(int i=0; i<myStringArray.length; i++) {
        if(myStringArray[i].contains("Name:"))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```